# from excel to Tableau - How to return the matrix product of two arrays in Tableau?

Tags: arrays, excel, tableau-api

I need to 'transform' something from excel to Tableau and I stuck with one point.
In excel I have function like that;

**{=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:A36),Sheet2!A$2:A$36)/SUM(Sheet2!A$2:A$36)}**

Do you know how to deal with it in Tableau?
I will be grateful for any tips and ideas

BR

EDIT:

So, in a nutshell:

First output:
Date1 (Jan,Jan,Jan)   Product1(A,B,C)     Value1 (X1,X2,X3)

Second output:
Date2(Jan,Jan,Jan)    Product2(A,B,C)     Value2 (Y1,Y2,Y3)

In excel I did MMULT function with transpose of column Value2 to get one value (record) as a result

[X1 X2 X3]

transpose [Y1
Y2
Y3]

So it is as ( X1*Y1 + X3*Y3 + X3Y3 ) = result

and I don't know how to get 'result' in Tableau

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem? Do you mean how to transpose/transform data in Tableau without doing it in source application/platform?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. 
Exactly, I have 2 data sources (sql queries and I rather not change anything there). I provided more details above - after EDIT

Answer (score 1):

See Tableau isn't a spreadsheet like excel where you can perform cell based iterations.

From your uploaded sample data, I suggest that you can proceed in tableau as follows-

- Join two tables/data sets in tableau using both 'date/month' and 'product' like date1 = date2 and product1 = product2
- Two `values` field will then be in the single row in merged data
- Create a new field by taking product of both values
- Create `{FIXED [...] : sum([value_product])}`

This way you will get matrix type multiplication of two arrays in a single field.

If you want me to demonstrate, please give at least a fair amount of **reproducible data** to work with.